# Sqlite select value as id to other table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working with SqLite, and I need connect table A with table B where the key is `guid` written as ["guid"] (TEXT). How do I accomplish that? (Should I use a substring value?)

#### Table A

```
|name| value    
|a   | ["13889483-d92a-483e-9e16-471cb22b82a3","a7ced9c5-e7bc-4214-be77-a26d8f86844b"]
```

#### Table B

```
| name                                 | value |
|13889483-d92a-483e-9e16-471cb22b82a3  | abc
```

Comment: what is "[xxx, yyy]" ?

Comment: This is id which refer to other table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your table A so it is in [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form):

```
Name  Value
a     13889483-d92a-483e-9e16-471cb22b82a3
a     a7ced9c5-e7bc-4214-be77-a26d8f86844b
```

Then you can connect the tables using a SQL join:

```
SELECT B.* FROM A
JOIN B ON B.Name = A.Value
WHERE A.Name = 'a'
```